# MySQL Counting Values when continuous criteria is true

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort out some data from a time logging table for user transactions. It is a simple data table with dates and an indicator of sale complete or abandoned..

This is some of the data

```
UserId  TimeStamp MonthName Code        Cost
1   01/01/2018  January SALE_COMPLETE   115.00
1   02/01/2018  January SALE_COMPLETE   199.00
1   03/01/2018  January SALE_COMPLETE   177.00
1   12/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  103.00
1   13/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  126.00
1   14/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  31.00
2   15/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  141.00
2   16/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  169.00
2   17/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  216.00
2   18/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  186.00
2   19/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  239.00
2   20/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  144.00
2   21/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  160.00
2   22/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  121.00
2   23/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  168.00
2   24/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  78.00
2   25/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  160.00
2   26/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  11.00
2   27/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  128.00
2   28/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  191.00
2   29/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  232.00
2   30/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  201.00
2   31/01/2018  January SALE_ABANDONED  109.00
2   01/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  160.00
2   02/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  103.00
2   03/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  146.00
2   04/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  22.00
2   05/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  74.00
2   06/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  102.00
2   07/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  66.00
2   08/02/2018  February    SALE_ABANDONED  118.00
```

What I am trying to do is get the total cost for **each user** when the code is SALE_ABANDONED and the code has **more than or equal to 5 instances** or **less than 5 instances**. And finally group over the months as a total.

So this is what I am looking to return

```
MonthName   >=5 CostLoss    <5 CostLoss
January     2654               260
February     791                0
```

Notice how UserId 2  still fits the >=5 category in February because it continues from January's instances of SALE_ABANDONED.

I hope this actually makes sense to someone, I know its quite tricky...

Comment: Why have you tagged both mysql AND oracle? Which one are you using actually?

Comment: Apologies.. MySQL

Comment: How did you get 636 and 263?

Comment: @anonyXmous - Excel mistake! updated

Comment: Is the data set properly representative of the problem, so no further sales will ever be completed?

Answer (score 0):

You need nested agregation, a simple count plus *conditional aggregation*:

```
select MonthName, 
   -- split the counts in two groups, ">=" and "<"
   sum(case when cnt >= 5 then sumCost else 0 end) as ">=5 CostLoss",
   sum(case when cnt  < 5 then sumCost else 0 end) as "<5 CostLoss"
from
 ( -- number of abandoned sales per user/month
    select UserId, MonthName, 
        sum(cost) as sumCost,
        count(*) as cnt
    from myTable
    where Code = 'SALE_ABANDONED'
    group by UserId, MonthName
) as dt
group by MonthName
```

Comment: This will simply count but not sum up the costs. Also, you missed the "from tableName" clause.

Comment: @anonyXmous: Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the sum of cost per month then sum up all those with less than 5 and greater than 5 costloss.

```
select MonthName, 
   sum(case when cnt >= 5 then sum_cost else 0 end) as ">=5 CostLoss",
   sum(case when cnt  < 5 then sum_cost else 0 end) as "<5 CostLoss"
from
 (  select UserId, 
           month(TStamp) as monthNum,
           MonthName,
           sum(Cost) as sum_cost,
           count(*) as cnt
    from yourTable
    where Code = 'SALE_ABANDONED'
    group by UserId, month(TStamp), MonthName
) as t
group by MonthName
order by monthNum  

Result:
   MonthName    >=5 CostLoss    <5 CostLoss
   January       2654            260
   February       791              0
```

Comment: Better switch to `order by min(monthNum)` to avoid failure in newer MySQL versions :-).